# Можно как-нибудь из флешки вызвать javascript?

Tags: flash, javascript

Есть на флешке кнопка, очень хочется, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывалось модальное окошко, написанное на jquery.
это как-то можно сделать?

Comment: А зачем?  
Сделайте всё во флэше. Тем более JavaScript и ActionScript очень похожи. Даже используют один стандарт ECMA.  


Comment: очень надо)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Курим [flash.external.externalinterface](http://www.google.ru/search?q=flash.external.externalinterface). Кратко: создаем функции в JS и AS и через эту штуку зовем из наших файлов.

Пример с моего сайта:

*HTML*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setTitle(str) {
  document.title = '[ '+str+' ]';
  return false;
  }
</script>
```

*FLASH*

```
flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("setTitle", t);
```